# django-compression static files on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, django-compressor

I'm trying to figure out how to get my compiled css working on Heroku. I'm using the django-compressor package to use SASS with my django project. Everything works perfectly on my local machine.

For this project, I would like to stay away from AWS S3 if possible. Much of what I'm seeing is a mixture of django-compression + django-storages.

In the heroku environment, here are the relevant settings:

```
# settings.py
DEBUG = True

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
  'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
```

When I run with these settings, I get a `OfflineGenerationError` and run `./manage.py compress` like it suggests, but the error remains although the file is created.

When I set `COMPRESS_OFFLINE = False`, after launching the Heroku app, the cached static file is not there as expected/designed. I run the compress command and it creates the file in /staticfiles/CACHE/css/asdf1234.css. In my browser, in the source it is searching for that exact file (but it is looking in STATIC_URL /static/CACHE/css/asdf1234.css), just like my other css files but it can't find the css file created by django-compressor?

When I make my settings exactly the same on dev as they are for my environment on Heroku, it works locally.

Comment: Can you check the user Django runs as has permissions to write to the static folder? You see the file created by Djagno at /static/CACHE/css/asdf1234.css but you can't get it directly from its URL?

Comment: yeah the permission is there, I'm able to create the file when running ./manage.py compress

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` must be an absolute path: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT  Also, are you sure that your web server serves from `/staticfiles/CACHE/css/...` when asking for `/static/CACHE/css`?

Comment: Did you solve this?